# Printing a list of files in a directory filtered by an extension in a modular way in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs, so please bear with me:

I want to create a program that prints a list of files in a given directory, filtered by the extension of the files where directory path and extension are given through command line arguments.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require("path");
fs.readdir(process.argv[2], function callback(list){
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    var p = process.argv[2]+"/"+list[i];
    var r=path.extname(p);
    if(r===("." + process.argv[3])){
        console.log(list[i]);
    }
}

});
```

The issue is that I want to do it in a modular way. I want write a module file to do most of the work. The module must export a single function that takes three arguments: the directory name, the filename extension string and a callback function, in that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick module based on your design:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var filterDir = function(dirPath, extension, cb) {
  fs.readdir(dirPath, function(err, list) {
    if (err) return cb(err);

    var filtered = list.map(function(fileName) {
      return path.join(dirPath, fileName);
    }).filter(function(filePath) {
      return path.extname(filePath) === extension;
    })

    cb(null, filtered);
  })
}

module.exports = filterDir;
```

You would call it like this, assuming the module is located in the same directory and named `filterDir.js`:

```
var filterDir = require('./filterDir');

var dirPath = process.argv[2];
var extension = '.' + process.argv[3];

filterDir(dirPath, extension, function(err, list) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(list);
})
```

Notice that Node.js uses error-first callbacks, so the first argument will be an error if one occurred, `null` if everything went fine. You might also just use `fs.readdirSync`, which means you don't have to deal with callbacks at all. The downside of that is your process can't do anything else while waiting for the file system to return, but if it's just a little script, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is readdirSync. you don't need a callback, you can just return the data. However, since you asked for it:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (directory, filename, callback) =>
    callback(require('fs').readdirSync(directory).filter(n => n.match(filename)));
```

And here is how you use it:

```
$ node
> e=require('./readdir');
[Function]
> e('.', '.js', console.log);
[ 'readdir.js', 'readdir.js.~1~' ]
undefined
> e('.','.js$',console.log);
[ 'readdir.js' ]
undefined
```